# Laravel dependency injection without relying on the controller

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out how to inject a dependency into a class in Laravel.

My structure:

```
SimpleController extends BaseController
{
    public function example(SimpleModel $model, SimpleValidationRequest $request)
    {
        $result = $model->doStuff()
        return $this->makeResponse($result);
    }
}

SimpleModel extends Model
{
    public function doStuff(ComplexService $service)
    {
        $service->doComplexLogic($this);
    }
}
```

I have registered the `ComplexService` in my own service provider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(ComplexService::class);
    }
}
```

I want to inject the service straight into the simpleModel's `doStuff` method, without having to inject it into the controller and then into the model. We're busy moving a monolithic application to Laravel and have service classes that contain all the complex business logic. Much of the logic is shared between different classes, so a controller method might call a model that calls a service that ends up making 4 or 5 calls to other services, and I want to be able to inject another service into any method that needs it without having to send it down from the controller all the way through to the bottom method that might need it.

Is there a way to do this? I have been looking online but everything I've found has required me to inject the service into the controller and then sending it through the application from there, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the singleton inside the method via the `app()` helper

```php
SimpleModel extends Model
{
    public function doStuff(ComplexService $service)
    {
        app()->singleton(ComplexService::class)->doComplexLogic($this);
    }
}
```

or recover the singleton by injecting it in the model via it's `__construct()` method.

Comment: I really don't want to inject the singleton into the construct method, and referencing the singleton directly doesn't feel/look like something I want to do, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that worked for you? I'm in the same boat right now and I'm not thrilled about consistently injecting service 4-5 classes down.